# SSL certificate stop's working after adding a SSL certificate to a website via C# code dynamically

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, ssl, https

I am Adding SSL certificate dynamically for every website host, and SSL cetificate get added for that particular site. But, the SSL doesn't work..I have to manually delete the Certificate then import the certifcate to make the SSL working.

My question is why after adding SSL dynamically via C# code, SSL gets added but does not work.?? Why i have to delete and import .pxf file manually to make it work? Do i need to add something in my code??

Code is as Follows:

```
ServerManager serverMgr = new ServerManager();

X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);


            X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Star_clouddunk_net.pfx", "w0rk");

            store.Add(certificate);

            var binding = mySite.Bindings.Add("*:443:" + strhostname + "", certificate.GetCertHash(), store.Name);
            binding.Protocol = "https";
            store.Close();

            serverMgr.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Where do you manually import the certificate into?  The code above is adding the certificate to StoreLocation.LocalMachine.  Does your process run as LocalSystem?  You could try importing into StoreLocation.CurrentUser.

Comment: I am import it manually via MMC.
Sart -> Run -> MMC.   

My process run on Server System.

Ok, i am trying with StoreLocation.CurrentUser, then will let you know

Comment: Steve : It worked man, i changed it from StoreLocation.LocalMachine to StoreLocation.CurrentUser (y)

Now the SSL is not breaking.